# How to extract data from Excel (specific columns) using SQL or PL/SQL or Python

Tags: java, python, sql, plsql

I was wondering if someone could help me understand how I could use Sql or Pl/Sql or python, or any convenient scripting language, to cherry pick specific data values (just a few columns on the excel sheet).

Any inputs would be highly appreciated!
Thanks!!

Comment: use [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can use `Apache POI` for that. 
https://poi.apache.org

Example:

```
// Creating a Workbook from an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx)
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("my_file.xlsx"));

// Getting the Sheet at index zero
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();

    // Now let's iterate over the columns of the current row
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use Pandas to drop the columns you do not want or you can keep the ones you do want. I suppose whichever list is smaller.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

#Drop Columns Not Needed
df = df.drop(['ColumnName1','ColumnName2'], axis=1)

#Keep Columns Needed
df = df[['ColumnName3','ColumnName4']]
```